# Why can't a field have a subring which is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

> Let $F$ be a field. Explain why $F$ cannot have a subring which is isomorphic to the ring $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$.

How to prove this?

Comment: Fields cannot have zero divisors; everything's invertible.

Answer (score 5):

Suppose that $R\subset F$ were a subring isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$.

Let $a,b\in R$ be the elements that correspond to $\overline{3},\overline{4}\in\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$.

Because $\overline{3},\overline{4}\neq \overline{0}$ in $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$, but $\overline{3}\cdot\overline{4}=\overline{0}$
in $\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$, we have that $a,b\neq 0$, but $ab=0$ in $R$ (and hence also in $F$) .

Now show that any two non-zero elements of a field cannot multiply to zero; that is, show that a field is an integral domain. This contradicts our conclusion above; thus our assumption (that this subring $R$ existed) must have been false. Thus, there can be no such subring $R$.

Answer (score 0):

If $F$ has characteristic $p>0$, then its [prime subfield](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PrimeSubfield.html) is $\mathbb{F}_p$. But if $F$ contains $\mathbb{Z}_{12}$, then $F$ contains also $\mathbb{F}_2$ and $\mathbb{F}_3$. You deduce that $p$ has to divide $2$ and $3$: it is just impossible since $p \geq 2$.